# VBA XML ChildNodes

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I am trying to modify a fine piece of code that i got from user2140261 that pulls data from the XML type (XBRL-Template) SEC EDGAR Database. So since i want to pull element values from other Nodes as well, my first idea was to show the list with the Nodes of the XML instance in a MsgBox; by using the [childNodes Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757053%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The first little snippet, has the minor modification I made to avoid any confusion while in the second one we see the original code plus the 3 statements of the modifications

```
Dim Tiger As String  

Tiger = objXMLNodexbrl.ChildNodes(1)

MsgBox Tiger
```

---

```
Sub GetNode()
Dim strXMLSite As String
Dim objXMLHTTP As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim objXMLDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim objXMLNodexbrl As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim objXMLNodeDIIRSP As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim Tiger As String

Set objXMLHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Set objXMLDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

strXMLSite = "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/10795/000119312513456802/bdx-20130930.xml"

objXMLHTTP.Open "POST", strXMLSite, False
objXMLHTTP.send
objXMLDoc.LoadXML (objXMLHTTP.responseText)

Set objXMLNodexbrl = objXMLDoc.SelectSingleNode("xbrl")

Tiger = objXMLNodexbrl.ChildNodes(1)

MsgBox Tiger

Set objXMLNodeDIIRSP = objXMLNodexbrl.SelectSingleNode("us-gaap:DebtInstrumentInterestRateStatedPercentage")

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = objXMLNodeDIIRSP.Text
End Sub
```

---

So when i am trying to parse step-by-step the code using an F8 i get a 'Runtime Error 438' telling me that the object doesn't support this property or method.

[image]

- How is that possible when [xbrl](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/10795/000119312513456802/bdx-20130930.xml) in the instance document is the root element and it contains all the child nodes?

@user2140261 wow you were so right...just one question i do change my code with

```
Tiger = objXMLNodexbrl.ChildNodes(1).Text
```

but i am getting the numerical value of the element instead of the number of the nodes. How is that possible? since ChildNodes Property : "Contains a node list containing the child nodes"...

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your line of code from:

```
Tiger = objXMLNodexbrl.ChildNodes(1)
```

To

```
Tiger = objXMLNodexbrl.ChildNodes(1).Text
```

***ALTERNATIVLY*** you could

change Tiger from a string to a MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

then change

```
MsgBox Tiger
```

To

```
MsgBox Tiger.Text
```

`objXMLNodexbrl.ChildNodes.Length` will return the count of nodes inside of `XBRL`

If you are trying to get a list of all Child Node Names of XBRL then Dim another MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode called `nodeCurrent` and use the following:

```
For Each nodeCurrent In objXMLNodexbrl.ChildNodes
    Tiger = Tiger & ", " & nodeCurrent.nodeName
Next nodeCurrent

MsgBox Tiger
```

Comment: Sir i have edited my question a little bit since you were right only to fix it and see another thing happening :P

Comment: Sir Thank you so much!!! MS don't have examples in MSXML2 for VBA only for C++ and JScript